# Unable to connect rabbitMQ using cluster IP server, it says connection is refused

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq

Unable to access rabbit MQ cluster IP service getting connection time out, however, I am able to connect using pod IP

how to connect to rabbitMQ 3.9  using cluster ip issue

Below is the manifest files used for deployment

### Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rmq-service
  namespace: qacommerece
  labels:
    app: rmq-service

spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: rmq-service
  ports:
    - name: rabbitmq
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
```

### Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-rc
  namespace: qacommerece
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rbq-service
  template:
    metadata:
      name: rbq-service
      labels:
        app: rbq-service
    spec:

      containers:
         - name: rabbitmq
           image: DevDigitalExperiencePlatformACR.azurecr.io/rabbitmq:latest
           env:
           - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
             value: rabbit
           - name: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
             value: 'rabbit'
           ports:
            - containerPort: 5672
```

RABBITMQ should work on cluster IP

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the selector of the Service.
Use selector `app: rbq-service` as defined in the deployment.

Comment: You could also change the label of the pod to `rmq-service` as alternative solution.